# NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder! issue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I've got a problem with a popup child:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14dET.png)

Once I click on the row I'm having this issue. But if I comment FormBuilder in the child component the popup works. Any idea how to solve it?

ParentComponent ts:

```
verifyRow($event: TableViewModel) {
        this.popupService.showDialog(ChildComponent, {
            firstId: $event.firstId,
            secondId: this.secondId
        }).subscribe();
    }
```

ParentComponent html:

```
<app-table (rowClicked)="verifyRow($event)"> </app-table>
```

PopUp service:

```
export class PopupService {
    constructor(@Inject(TuiDialogService) private readonly dialogService: TuiDialogService) { }

    showDialog(component: Type<object>, data: any = null, dismissible: boolean = true, closeable: boolean = true): Observable<any> {
        return this.dialogService.open<any>(
            new PolymorpheusComponent(component),
            {
                data: data,
                size: 'l',
                dismissible: dismissible,
                closeable: closeable
            },
        );
    }
}
```

ChildComponent ts:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    data: DiffModel;
    @Input() firstId: number;
    @Input() secondId: number;
    currentForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
              private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
              private toast: AlertToastService,
              private popupService: PopupService,,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              private cdk: ChangeDetectorRef) { }



  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
      this.apiService.getByOrder(this.firstId).subscribe({
          next: res => {
          this.data = res;
          },
          error: err => {
              console.log(err);
          }
      })
  }

  add() {
      this.popupService.showDialog(DiffChildComponent, this.firstId).subscribe({
          next: data => {
              this.currentForm = this.fb.group({
                  id: [0, []],
                  firstId: this.firstId,
                  secondId: this.secondId,
              })
              console.log(this.currentForm.value)
              this.apiService.add(this.currentForm.value).subscribe({
                  next: res => {
                      res ?
                          this.toast.showNotification(data ? "approvedSuccessfully" : "refusedSuccessfully", "", TuiNotification.Success):
                          this.toast.showNotification("failed", "", TuiNotification.Error);
                      this.generalHelper.reloadPage();
                      },
                  error: e => this.toast.showServerError(e)
              });
              },
          complete: () => {
              console.log('Dialog closed');
              },
        })
    }
}
```

Also i have FormModule and ReactiveFormsModule in every Module and this child components works fine without parent.

Comment: What is the import path of `FormBuilder`?

Comment: Hi, import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

Comment: @RandomBeginner which version of Angular are you using ?

Comment: Please provide the version of @angular/core

Comment: @angular-devkit/architect       0.1200.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.0.5
@angular-devkit/core            12.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.0.5
@angular/animations             12.2.16
@angular/cdk                    12.2.13
@angular/localize               12.2.16
@schematics/angular             12.0.5
rxjs                            7.1.0
typescript                      4.2.4

Comment: Seems good, could you provide a [mcve] on stackblitz reproducing the issue ?

Comment: the problem is that it is a company's project and it's too big

Comment: u have no idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm right or not (not having your issue replicated in a stackblitz instance or something similar), but I think the issue is in the first `next` of the `add` method where you are doing this

```
this.currentForm = this.fb.group({
  id: [0, []],
  firstId: this.firstId,
  secondId: this.secondId,
})
```

It seems to me that you are trying to update the form control values but for this you would need to use the `patchValue` or the `setValue` method. Something like this:

```
this.currentForm.setValue({
  id: [0, []],
  firstId: this.firstId,
  secondId: this.secondId,
})
```

Comment: doesn't change anything